Dispose Pattern in C#: Implementing Dispose and GC.SuppressFinalize
I am studying the Dispose pattern in C#, and I understand that the Dispose method is used when there are unmanaged resources. For example, if I have an unmanaged resource in FirstClass, and FirstClass is contained within a Node class, I need to implement the Dispose method for both, right?
What I don't understand the most is whether I need to call GC.SuppressFinalize(this); in every Dispose method.
GC.SuppressFinalize(this); instructs the garbage collector not to finalize, but does this mean that GC.SuppressFinalize(this); is only necessary in the Dispose method if the class has a finalizer? If that's the case, I think it would be needed in both the Node class and BaseClass. However, since the Node class also has managed members, is it acceptable to suppress the finalizer in that case?
I am confused because there are nested classes with Dispose methods.
  public class Node : IDisposable
  {
    public Node Next { get; set; } = null;
    public Node Child { get; set; } = null;
    
    public FirstClass CppInstance { get; set; } = null;

    public Node()
    {
      CppInstance = new FirstClass();
    }
    
    ~Node()
    {
      this.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this.CppInstance?.Dispose();
    }
  }
  
  public class FirstClass : BaseClass
  {
    private List<String> _nameList = [];
    
    public FirstClass()
    {
       CreateCppData( out _instance );// C++ Function create
       _nameList.Add("A");
       _nameList.Add("B");
       _nameList.Add("C");
    }
    
    protected override void Dispose( Boolean disposing )
    {
      if( !disposedValue )
      {
        if( disposing )
        {
          // Managed resource release
          _nameList.Clear();
          _nameList = null;
        }

        // Unmanaged resource release
        DeleteCppData( ref _instance ); // C++ Function delete
        disposedValue = true;
      }
    }
  
  }

  public class BaseClass :IDisposable
  {
    protected Boolean disposedValue = false;

    protected IntPtr _instance;  // ● Unmanaged Data
    
    ~BaseClass()
    {
      Dispose( false );
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose( Boolean disposing )
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this.Dispose( disposing: true );
      GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {
    }
  }


C#  I rewrote it based on the advice.
  public class Node : IDisposable
  {
    public Node Next { get; set; } = null;
    public Node Child { get; set; } = null;
    
    public FirstClass FirstClassInstance { get; set; } = null;
    protected Boolean disposedValue = false;

    public Node()
    {
      FirstClassInstance = new FirstClass();
    }
    
    ~Node()
    {
      this.Dispose( false );
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this.Dispose( true );
      GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }
    
    protected virtual void Dispose( Boolean disposing )
    {
      if( !disposedValue )
      {
        this.FirstClassInstance?.Dispose();
        this.FirstClassInstance = null;
        disposedValue = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  public class FirstClass : BaseClass
  {
    private List<String> _nameList = [];
    
    public FirstClass()
    {
       _nameList.Add("A");
       _nameList.Add("B");
       _nameList.Add("C");
    }
    
    protected override void Dispose( Boolean disposing )
    {
      if( !disposedValue )
      {
        if( disposing )
        {
          // Managed resource release
          _nameList.Clear();
          _nameList = null;
        }
        
        base.Dispose( disposing ); // BaseClass Dispose
      }
    }
    
    protected override void CreateCppInstance()
    {
       CreateCppData( out _instance ); // C++ Function create
    }

    protected override void DeleteCppInstance()
    {
       DeleteCppData( ref _instance ); // C++ Function delete
    }
  }

  public class BaseClass :IDisposable
  {
    protected Boolean disposedValue = false;

    protected IntPtr _instance;  // ● Unmanaged Data

    public BaseClass()
    {
      CreateCppInstance();
    }    
    
    ~BaseClass()
    {
      Dispose( false );
    }
    
    protected virtual void CreateCppInstance()
    {
      throw new Exception();
    }

    protected virtual void DeleteCppInstance()
    {
      throw new Exception();
    }

    protected override void Dispose( Boolean disposing )
    {
      if( !disposedValue )
      {
        if( disposing )
        {
          // Managed resource release
        }
        // Unmanaged resource release
        DeleteCppInstance();
        disposedValue = true;
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this.Dispose( disposing: true );
      GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }
  }


You really shouldn't edit the question in response to answers, that ends up invalidating the answers and makes it hard for community members to learn from. Either post as your own answer and include a commentary on why you are doing so, or post a new follow up question (you can link to this post) or add your edit as a block after the original question content.

I placed the original code at the top.

The discussion in this question Dispose() for cleaning up managed resources? covers this indirectly.
The real question here is

is GC.SuppressFinalize(this); only necessary in the Dispose method if the this class has a finalizer?

Generally, YES.
The general use case for suppressing the finalizer in dispose is when your finalizer also calls Dispose(), which is a standard practise so that we only have to write our resource cleanup logic once. Suppressing the finalizer prevents re-entry to the Dispose logic that has already been executed.
If your class does not implement a finalizer, then you would not bother suppressing the finalizer. In the case of inheritance, you might want to suppress the finalizer if you didn't have control of the base class implementation and you knew that you wanted to suppress the logic, presumably because you elevated the same logic to your local dispose method. But this would be a poor design and is only an advanced workaround that you implement after identifying issues at runtime, it shouldn't be your default design. It would be better for your local implementation to only clean up resources that your local class owns and to call the base implementation of dispose from your local class to clean up any resources in the base. If the base implementation needs to suppress finalize, then it should.

If your local class does implement a finalizer, and that finalizer only calls Dispose(), then you would normally suppress the finalizer in the dispose logic.


Thank you.I see, I should only suppress the finalizer with GC.SuppressFinalize(this) when there is a finalizer. I rewrote the code based on your advice.
While writing the code, a question occurred to me: In the Dispose pattern, managed resources are released in the “if (disposing){}” block, but won't they be released automatically without writing it here? In what cases is it correct to use this block? Is it mainly for passwords or other sensitive information that you absolutely want to delete?

The point of disposing is to either release resources or references to them. This is not really designed for removing sensitive information at all. For managed resources it is not necessary to set them to null, but it removes them from the current scope. If the variable you are cleaning up does not implement IDisposable you might still want to remove any event handlers or other callbacks that might be registered or referenced by external objects. Setting a reference variable to null only nulls the reference, not the object itself.

I see, it’s more about clearing things like event handlers or callbacks from external objects. That makes sense.
Thank you so much for explaining!

The Node class indeed needs to implement IDisposable since it owns IDisposable resources (FirstClass instance). However, it should not implement a finalizer since it does not own any unmanaged resources itself. Calling another object's Dispose method from a finalizer is not a good idea since the other object might already have been finalized. Consider what happens if the FirstClass instance somehow refers back to the Node: the runtime will finalize both instances but cannot do this in dependency order.
As for GC.SuppressFinalize(this) in Dispose, this is harmless in any case (since depending on a finalizer on a disposed object is way too tricky), but it is only useful if the class has a finalizer or it is not sealed. If a class is not sealed and does not call GC.SuppressFinalize(this) in Dispose, an inheriting class with a finalizer will have to re-implement IDisposable. Suppressing the finalizer relieves the garbage collector of the need to promote the object to the next generation to finalize it (so the object's memory will become available for new use sooner).
Consider sealing Node and/or unifying FirstClass with BaseClass and sealing it since this allows avoiding the somewhat complicated dispose pattern. In other words, designing for inheritance has a cost, which should only be paid when it is justified.

I hadn't considered whether to use sealed or not; this is very informative. Thank you. I will consider sealing it.
